# Keep primefaces socket (push) connection after page refresh

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download, push

I'm using Primefaces `fileDownload` triggered by a `commandButton` to allow the user to export his work (as a serialized POJO)... which only exists in a view scope (as long as it has not been exported!)

### fileDownload XHTML template:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save worksheet" icon="ui-icon-disk"
    ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)">
    <p:fileDownload
         value="#{applicationManager.applicationController.saveWorksheet()}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

### saveWorksheet() method

```
    @Override
    public StreamedContent saveWorksheet() {
    StreamedContent worksheetFile = null;
    try {
        String worksheetFilename = sessionDirectories + sessionId + "/worksheet.wbc";
        System.out.println("saveWorksheet");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(worksheetFilename);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(historyList);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();

        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(worksheetFilename);
        worksheetFile = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/wbc", "worksheet.wbc");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return worksheetFile;
}
```

(`historyList` is just an ArrayList of history records)

This file downloading feature is working fine. The problem is that I'm using Primefaces `push` to display the result of the command sent by the user (because I need to display it on every client sharing the same URL fragment). But since `fileDownload` triggered by a `commandButton` needs a full page refresh, the socket disconnects on download start.

(*note*: the socket is connected in the `applicationManager` bean which is view scoped).

### Socket XHTML template:

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleOutput" channel="/terminalOutput"
            widgetVar="subscriber" />
```

### Socket connection:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("subscriber.connect('/" + sessionId + "')");
```

**Is there any way to make the socket connection survive a page refresh? is there a way to define the scope of the socket?**

Many thanks in advance for your help :)

Regards,

Zim

Comment: have you tried session scope?

Comment: Session scope for what?
The applicationManager bean must be view scoped, so I tried to put the socket connection code line in a session scoped bean, but it doesn't work either :(

Comment: I am afraid anything under view scope won't survive a page refresh

Comment: I agree, and I'm afraid the socket connection lives only within the view generated by the XHTML template file that contains the `<p:socket>` tag. So, it can't have anything else than a view scope!
As a workaround, I just reconnect it in the `stop` callback of the `Primefaces.monitorDownload` function... seems to do the trick but sooo ugly :(